# An app. which make calls through net not using using phone balance

Tags: android

I want to create a app. which will allow the user to dial a number given by using net connectivity. please help.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/help/asking

Answer (score 0):

I'm sorry but i can't comment just yet, but can you give us some more information? You want to get a number via net connectivity or make a call via net connectivity?

If you have the number, you can dial it by executing this code:

```
 Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_DIAL);
 intent.setData(Uri.parse("1234567890"))
 startActivity(intent);
```

Comment: I want to make a call through net connectivity

Comment: maybe this will help [link](https://www.sinch.com/tutorials/android-app-to-app-calling-tutorial/)